# Proving Eulers totient function is multiplicative

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

There is a proof at the bottom of page 1, I understand it up until the point where it says "*It follows from Theorem
4.7 of Rosen that the entries in such a row form a complete residue system
modulo n. Thus, exactly $\phi(n)$ of them will be relatively prime to $n$, and
thus relatively prime to $mn$.*" I don't know where the theorem is, but would appreciate if someone could explain why an element would have to be in one of the $\phi(n)$ rows such that it is coprime with $mn$.

http://gauss.math.luc.edu/greicius/Math201/Fall2012/Lectures/euler-phi.article.pdf

Comment: I believe the theorem in question is: If $a$, $b$, $k$, and $m$ are integers such that $k>0$, $m>0$, and $a\equiv b\pmod m$, then $a^k\equiv b^k\pmod m$.

Comment: For the title, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3046542/prove-eulers-totient-function-is-multiplicative).